# explanation of beta random variable

Tags: self-learning, time-series, beta-function

I've been reading a paper for self study on the beta-egarch model here:
https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/42337476.pdf

One of the things I don't understand is how the following:

$$
b_{t}=\frac{(y_{t}-\mu)^{2}/\left[\nu \exp(2\lambda_{t|t-1})\right]}{1+(y_{t}-\mu)^{2}/\left[\nu \exp(2\lambda_{t|t-1})\right]}
$$

is a $B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})$

My initial idea was $$
\left(1+(y_{t}-\mu)^{2}/\left[\nu \exp(2\lambda_{t|t-1})\right]\right)^{??-1}.\left((y_{t}-\mu)^{2}/\left[\nu \exp(2\lambda_{t|t-1})\right]\right)^{??-1}
$$

but even then, I don't understand how to arise to the powers of required beta distribution.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can get proper formatting for functions like $\exp$ by using `\exp`. For operators that don't happen to have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: I didn't realise about the \exp until you mentioned it now, thanks.